# Cannot load the assets on home page and Form Builder page (Orbeon)

Tags: orbeon

I compiled the source code of Orbeon Forms, and find out that some of the css and JS cannot be expectedly imported. May I get some suggestions for this issue?

Orbeon Version: Orbeon Forms 2022.1 CE

java --version
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)

sbt --version
sbt version in this project: 1.6.2
sbt script version: 1.6.2

ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013

orbeon.log:

2022-07-13T17:36:21,356 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "32", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "20 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,357 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "32", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: nofilter", "time": "21 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,370 INFO  ProcessorService - /ops/images/xforms/remove.gif - Timing: 16
2022-07-13T17:36:21,370 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "33", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "16 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,370 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "33", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: nofilter", "time": "16 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,383 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/ops/yui/container/assets/skins/sam/container.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,384 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,385 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/form-runner-bootstrap-override.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,385 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,386 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/config/theme/xforms.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,387 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/config/theme/error.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,387 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/ops/nprogress-0.2.0/nprogress.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,387 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/ops/css-loader/css-loader.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,387 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/form-runner-common.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,388 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/form-runner-base.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,388 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/form-runner-orbeon.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,388 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/forms/orbeon/builder/resources/form-builder.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,388 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/date/date.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,389 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/date/bootstrap-datepicker-1.8.0-dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,389 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/number/number.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,390 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server/orbeon-8517678e6cb7908bfdbeb36f205f9e185838b639.css - Timing: 134
2022-07-13T17:36:21,391 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "24", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "134 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,392 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "24", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: nofilter", "time": "136 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,413 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/fb/dialog-itemsets/dialog-itemsets.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,414 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/fb/parameters-editor/parameters-editor.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,414 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/fb/permissions/permissions.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,414 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/alert-dialog/alert-dialog.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,414 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/attachment/attachment.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,415 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/box-select/box-select.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,415 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/character-counter/character-counter.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,415 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/checkbox-input/checkbox-input.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,415 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/lib/codemirror.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,415 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/code-mirror.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,416 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/fold/foldgutter.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,416 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/dialog/dialog.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,416 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,416 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/databound-select1/databound-select1.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,416 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/dropdown-select1-search.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,417 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,417 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/datetime/datetime.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,417 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/ops/dragula/dragula.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,417 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-date/dropdown-date.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,418 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/css/select2.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,418 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/error-summary/error-summary.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,418 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/fields-date/fields-date.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,418 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/grid/grid.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,418 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/hidden/hidden.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,419 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/image/image.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,419 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/ladda-button/ladda-1.0.0-orbeon/ladda-themeless.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,419 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/ladda-button/ladda-button.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,419 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/open-select1/open-select1.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,419 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/repeater/repeater.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,420 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/section/section.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,420 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tabbable/tabbable.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,420 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/time/time.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,420 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/tinymce.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,420 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,420 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,421 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/us-phone/us-phone.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,421 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/us-state/us-state.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,421 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/inc/wColorPicker.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,421 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/wPaint.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,421 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/wpaint.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,422 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/apps/fr/style/form-runner-responsive.css"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,422 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server/orbeon-514f23f23eeac35d60acb6b76da3e1b0f31c674c.css - Timing: 164
2022-07-13T17:36:21,423 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "25", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "164 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,424 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "25", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: nofilter", "time": "166 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,430 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/autosize-textarea/autosize.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/lib/codemirror.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/mode/xml/xml.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/fold/foldcode.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/fold/foldgutter.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/fold/xml-fold.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/dialog/dialog.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/search/searchcursor.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/search/search.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,431 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/scroll/annotatescrollbar.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,432 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,432 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/codemirror-5.65.5/addon/search/jump-to-line.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,432 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/code-mirror.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,432 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/select2.full.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,432 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/fr.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,432 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/de.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/sv.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/pt.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/it.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/es.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/fi.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/nl.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/ru.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/pl.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1-search/select2-4.0.13/js/i18n/da.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,433 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/ladda-button/ladda-1.0.0-orbeon/spin.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,434 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/ladda-button/ladda-1.0.0-orbeon/ladda.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,434 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,434 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,434 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,434 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,434 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/inc/jquery.ui.core.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,435 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/inc/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,435 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/inc/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,435 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/inc/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,435 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/inc/wColorPicker.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,435 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/xbl/orbeon/wpaint/1.13.1/wPaint.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,435 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/ops/javascript/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,436 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server/orbeon-99132dbc9b8327d754e1bc2e22edb1bb7e2cb20a.js - Timing: 169
2022-07-13T17:36:21,437 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "26", "session": "8C7A884962FB547496F104184B3AB793", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "170 ms"}
2022-07-13T17:36:21,437 ERROR XFormsServer - could not read asset to aggregate {asset: "/ops/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"}

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyoRW.png)

[Form Builder Start Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAT7A.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This might be a new issue on master. Try building from the 2020.1-ce branch and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: See also https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5384.

Comment: @ebruchez
I have tried for 2020.1-ce branch but I still cannot fluently run `npm install`, even throgh follow the instructions in order to solve the error related.

Comment: What version of npm and node do you have?

Comment: @ebruchez [npm -version 8.11.0]  [node --version v16.15.1]

Comment: @Chad Ok, asking I have node v12.13.1. If you use nvm can you try `nvm use 12` to see if building with that works?

Comment: @ebruchez Many thanks for you suggestion. Npm build works. But I still have problem about the sbt build. Error log is mainly about `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": Malformed argument has embedded quote: [[\"C:\\Users\\User12345\\Desktop\\orbeon-forms-2020.1-ce\\src\\main\\assets\\config\\theme\\examples.less\",\"config\\theme\\examples.less\"]]`

Comment: Good to hear about the first part. Not sure why it can't run node though: maybe it should be in the path and isn't?

Comment: @ebruchez The log is from the cmd run `sbt` then run `package` in the project directory

Comment: @ebruchez Is that something wrong for running `package` in the `sbt` build, that makes the `sbt` cannot recognize `node`? Very grateful if you can provide suggestions for this issue.

Comment: It should just work. I wonder if this is related to building on Windows. I don't build on Windows so I cannot tell. Do you have a way to build on Linux or Mac OS?

Comment: @ebruchez oh I see, I built it on Window